# error: cannot convert 'bool' to 'svLogic*' in assignment

Tags: c++, gcc, system-verilog, modelsim, system-verilog-dpi

We are working on the system verilog DPI calls. While compiling the `C++` file we are getting the errors like this:

> error: cannot convert 'bool' to 'svLogic*' in assignment

Here `svLogic` is 4-state variable.

The VCS simulator has predefined function in DirectC method `vc_putScalar`,  where vc_putScalar is *"Passes the value of a scalar reg or bit to a vc_handle by reference"*. The vc_handle is input or output variable in function. With VCS we could use: `vc_putScalar(mem_req_rdy, mm->req_cmd_ready());`

We are working on Modelsim questa simulator so DirectC will not work. We are tiring to modify the `vc_putScalar` into w.r.t of DPI [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) standards.
We changed the predefined function logic into this:
`mem_req_rdy = mm->req_cmd_ready();` Here mem_req_rdy is svLogic and req_cmd_ready is bool.

Comment: You have identified "svLogic is 4-state variable" as the only pertinent information about the issue, but it was not enough for you to resolve things, so you had to ask here. What does that tell you?

Comment: it's not an enum. The svlogic variable is input variable of C++ function. In system verilog svlogic is 4-state variable it can give values  like 0,1,X,Z.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Please post what this function looks like and the assignment statement that's causing the error. If you'd done that to begin with, you'd have had an answer by now instead of a couple of downvotes. It sounds like you need to dereference the `svLogic` instance before assigning it the `bool` value.

Comment: @SanthoshKumat Please share the code. I hope you are including svdpi.h header file. svLogic type is nothing but an alias(typedef) to uint8_t. So assignment from bool is never an issue for me.

Comment: @Coverify thank for replay. I added svdpi.h file in C++ file. I am not familiar with C++. could you please help on this issue. It will more help for me.

Comment: @SathoshKumar If we go by the error you are getting mem_req_rdy is not svLogic but svLogic*. Can you please check?

Comment: @SathoshKumar you perhaps need *mem_req_rdy = mm->req_cmd_ready(); Note the indirection to mem_req_rdy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you had:

```
vc_putScalar(mem_req_rdy, mm->req_cmd_ready());
```

I am guessing that **mem_req_rdy** is of pointer type **svLogic*** (since from the name of the function **vc_putScalar**, it seems that it intends to change the value held in **mem_req_rdy**). So you need to dereference the pointer as in the following statement:

```
*mem_req_rdy = mm->req_cmd_ready();
```

Answer (score 0):

> error: cannot convert 'bool' to 'svLogic*' in assignment

`svLogic` seems to be a pointer. You cannot assign a `bool` value to a pointer variable.

```
TYPE* p = /* initialized somehow */;
bool b = /* initialized somehow */;
p = b;  // YOU CANNOT DO THAT
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to re-think your DPI interface. Does your C code really need to deal with 4-state logic?

In many cases, no access routines are needed to access arguments passed between the two languages. This is always true is the passing types are C-compatible (int, byte,string, and unpacked arrays and structs of these types).

For example this DirectC example

```
SV:
extern "C" void foo(input bit A, output bit B);
C:
void foo(vc_handle A, vc_handle B)
{ vc_scalar value;
  value = vc_getSalar(A);
 vc_putScalar(B,value);
}
```

translates to this DPI code

```
SV:
import "DPI-C" void foo(input bit A, output bit B);
C:
void foo(svBit A, svBit *B)
{ svBit value;
  value = A;
 *B = value;
}
```

We strongly recommend that Questa DPI users use the vlog -dpiheader filename.h, switch and then their C code should #include that file. Then the compiler will catch any mismatches in the syntax of argument handling.

Comment: Hi Deve, thank for reply. We are trying to compile the C++ files which have VCS routines and the vcs routines are **vc_getScalar, vc_putScalar, vc_put4stVector, vc_4stVectorRef** How to replace these routines with normal C++ logic.

Comment: The example I gave above shows how you can eliminate the vc_getScalar and vc_putScalar routines. For the other routines, you will need to understand _Annex H DPI C layer_ in the 1800-2012 LRM, specifically sections 10,11, & 12. Without seeing and understanding the original code, it is difficult to suggest the best translation.  I suggest you work on a small example first, like the one in <questadir>/examples/systemverilog/dpi/packed_types to get a better understanding of how the DPI works first before attempting to translate the code.

Answer (score 0):

svLogic is a typedef of `unsiged char`, see [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § H.10.1.1 *Scalars of type bit and logic*

For a bool to svLogic conversion you need a function, not a direct assignment. If the bool value is true, then the svLogic should be assigned to `sv_1`. If the bool value is falue, then the svLogic should be assigned to `sv_0`.

Something like this should work:

```
mem_req_rdy = mm->req_cmd_ready() ? sv_1 : sv_0;
```